# Add css class to parent of radio button when checked using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to add a css class to the  div.from of my radio button if it is checked. Then remove if it is not checked.

**And the html:**

```
<div style="width:49.5%;height:auto;float:left;" class="from">


<label>
<div class="fromm" id="order">
    <div class="frairimg"></div>
    <div class="frfromdetails"></div>
    <div class="frarrow"></div>
    <div class="frfromdetails"></div>
    <div class="frrefund"></div>
    <div class="radio"><input type="radio" name="from" id="something" class="getvalue"></div>
    <div class="frfnumber"></div>
    <div class="roundfare"></div>
</div>
</label>

<label>
<div class="fromm" id="order1">
    <div class="frairimg"></div>
    <div class="frfromdetails"></div>
    <div class="frarrow"></div>
    <div class="frfromdetails"></div>
    <div class="frrefund"></div>
    <div class="radio"><input type="radio" name="from" id="something1" class="getvalue"></div>
    <div class="frfnumber"></div>
    <div class="roundfare"></div>
</div>
</label>

  <label>
<div class="fromm" id="order2">
    <div class="frairimg"></div>
    <div class="frfromdetails"></div>
    <div class="frarrow"></div>
    <div class="frfromdetails"></div>
    <div class="frrefund"></div>
    <div class="radio"><input type="radio" name="from" id="something2" class="getvalue"></div>
    <div class="frfnumber"></div>
    <div class="roundfare"></div>
</div>
</label>                                  

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
<style>
.checked11 { background: red; }
</style>
```

**Here's what I came up with in jquery:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input:radio').click(function() {
    $('input:radio[name='+$(this).attr('name')+']').parent().removeClass('checked11');
        $(this).parent().addClass('checked11');

    });
});

</script>
```

here my problem is the class is applying for radio button only but want it to apply for  div.from

Thankyou.
Naresh Kamireddy

Comment: well, parent() does not need a parameter, just write $(this).parent()

Comment: Cant we specify the path of the to be applyed

Comment: Your sample is working. it is applying `checked11` for the div that containing `radio` class. http://jsfiddle.net/fq8Zn/

Comment: You should be clear about what you actually want. In your question you say you want to style the "parent div" but in the comments you say the "div with class .from" which doesn't make too much sense since all your radios are in this div. Don't you actually want to style each radio's closest `div.fromm`?

Comment: I want to apply it for the div.from

Comment: So you want to style the `div.from` if one of its descendent radios is checked. In this case I assume you have multiple `.from` divs with different radio groups?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*If I understand correctly, there are 2 requirements to this question.*

**Upon selecting a radio button:**

1. The CSS class `checked11` should be **added** to the parent of the selected radio button.
2. The CSS class `checked11` should be **removed** from any parents of now no longer selected radio buttons.

If this is the case, then the following should work:

```
var $radioButtons = $('input[type="radio"]');
$radioButtons.click(function() {
    $radioButtons.each(function() {
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('checked11', this.checked);
    });
});
```

### [jsFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/GeekyEggo/mjp33/)

Answer (score 3):

Here's the **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vonDy2791/54JUq/1/)**

```
  $('input:radio').click(function () {
      $('input:radio').parent().removeClass('checked11');
      $(this).parent(this).addClass('checked11');
  });
```

Comment: still the same problem is coming when i was implementing in my code, instead of applying for <div class="from">/div> it is applying for   <div class="radio">/div>

Answer (score 1):

Finally i got my answer....

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $radioButtons = $('input[type="radio"]');
$radioButtons.click(function() {
    $radioButtons.each(function() {
        $(this).closest('.fromm').toggleClass('checked11', this.checked);
    });
});
});
```

Thank you for all spending your valuable time for my question....

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

```
 $(this).closest('.fromm').addClass('checked11');
```

Comment: how about using .closest()

Comment: if closest() means it applys for closest div, but i want it to apply for the div which class is 'from'

Comment: if you want to add class on 'from', then change '.radio' to '.from'

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('input:radio').change(function(){
      var $self = $(this);
      if ($self.prop('checked')) {
         $self.parent().addClass('checked11');
      } else {
         $self.parent().removeClass('checked11');
      }
   });
});
```

[Edit] http://jsfiddle.net/jtpU6/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('input:radio').change(function(){
      $('div:has(input:radio)').removeClass('checked11');
      var $self = $(this);
      if ($self.prop('checked')) {
         $self.parent().addClass('checked11');
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: Alternatively you could use `toggleClass`, like so: `$self.parent().toggleClass('checked11', $self.prop('checked'));`

Answer (score 0):

You also have a little weird selector of the input.

$(this) is the clicked element, you dont need to search for input radios which name matches the clicked input's name, just use $(this) - and $(this).parent() to select the clicked parent:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input:radio').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().removeClass('checked11').addClass('checked11');
    });
});
```

Comment: i made small changes to your code and it is working perfect, thank you